# I am trying to display element data inside tooltip. But the tooltip doesnot seem to work. is it because of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I need to display the content inside tooltip,but tooltip doesnot seem to work.

```
<div data-ng-model="de.de_data" data-toggle="tooltip"  class="de-col-div  contentBorder" id="de-col-div-text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-click="some function" tooltip="{{de.de_data}}" >
{{de.de_data}}
</div>
```

Comment: which directive are you using for tooltip?

Comment: I am using 'ui-bootstrap' library. have not written any particular directive for  tooltip

Comment: Which version of ui-bootstrap?

Comment: You can use   uib-tooltip="{{}}"

Comment: uib-tooltip="{{}}" is working on every div except this one @neda

Comment: Please check your bootstrap version .

Comment: Version: 0.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `data-toggle` attribute when used with angular-ui-bootstrap

```
 <div uib-tooltip="{{de.de_data}}" class="de-col-div contentBorder" id="de-col-div-text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-click="some function" >
     {{de.de_data}}
 </div>
```

Comment: The content i want to write in tooltip is long texts. In normal "title" attribute it displays entire thing in single line. Using "tooltip" it displays in a neat word wrapped fashion. I have been using tooltip attribute but only for this div ot fails to give result.

Comment: Updated answer, the answer is based on ui-bootstrapv2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong.Try this way

```
<div data-ng-model="de.de_data" 
     data-toggle="tooltip"  
     class="de-col-div  
     contentBorder" 
     id="de-col-div-text" 
     ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
     ng-click="some function" tooltip="de.de_data" >
         {{de.de_data}}
</div>
```

Sample fiddle here
http://fiddle.jshell.net/3j7dnftt/

Comment: but its working in the fiddle as u can see, u have included the bootstrap files right?